# PowerShell automation build for Release x86

Tags: powershell

Hi all I have written a PowerShell script to automate the build which works fine for debug mode

Clean

```
$Configuration = "Debug"
$BuildArgs = @{            
  FilePath = $MsBuild            
  ArgumentList = $SlnFilePath, "/t:clean", ("/p:Configuration=" + $Configuration), "/v:minimal"            
  RedirectStandardOutput = $BuildLog            
  Wait = $true                        
}                      
Start-Process @BuildArgs
```

Build

```
 $Configuration = "Debug"

$BuildArgs = @{            
  FilePath = $MsBuild            
  ArgumentList = $SlnFilePath, "/t:rebuild", ("/p:Configuration=" + $Configuration), "/v:minimal"            
  RedirectStandardOutput = $BuildLog            
  Wait = $true                        
}                      
Start-Process @BuildArgs
```

But when I change the argumentlist as follows

`ArgumentList = $SlnFilePath, "/t:clean", ("/p:Configuration=Release /p:PlatformTarget=86"), "/v:minimal"` this is not cleaning up and rebuilding the solution can some one help me

Answer (score 0):

I got it
Modified this
`ArgumentList = $SlnFilePath, "/t:clean", ("/p:Configuration=Release /p:PlatformTarget=86"), "/v:minimal"`

as follows

`ArgumentList = $SlnFilePath, "/t:clean", ("/p:Configuration=Release /p:PlatformTarget=X86"), "/v:minimal"`